# Draggable pixmaps inside a QGraphicsScene of graphic items

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicspixmapitem

I have a scene with a 12*4 grid with blocks of QGraphicsItems ,when i right click  on the blocks I have a contexmenu that
 can add icons inside the blocks my proplem is that
I can't fingure out how can I make those icons draggable to the other blocks inside the graphic scene ,I know there is the "Draggable Icons Example" but how can I implement that code to a graphic scene.

this is the mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsPathItem>
class QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent;
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *);
~MainWindow();

private slots:
void showContextMenu(const QPoint&);
void addPixBlock();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
QGraphicsScene *scene;
QGraphicsItem *itemAt(const QPointF&);

int x;
int y;

QMenu *Menu;
QMenu *Submenu;
QAction *Picture;
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pix;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

the mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "block.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QPainter>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this) ;
for(int row=-4;row<8;++row)
  for(int column=0;column<4;++column)
{
  Block *b = new Block;
  scene->addItem(b);
  b->setPos(row* 95,column*85);
}
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
scene->installEventFilter(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
QGraphicsItem* MainWindow::itemAt(const QPointF &pos)
{
QList<QGraphicsItem*> items = scene->items(QRectF(pos - QPointF(1,1), 
QSize(3,3)));

foreach(QGraphicsItem *item, items)
     if (item->type() > QGraphicsItem::UserType)
     return item;
 return 0;
  }
 bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
  {
 QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *me = (QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*) e;

 switch ((int) e->type()){

 case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress:{

 switch ((int) me->button()){

  case Qt::RightButton:{

     QGraphicsItem *item = itemAt(me->scenePos());

     if (item && item->type() == Block::Type){
         x=item->scenePos().x();
         y=item->scenePos().y();
        showContextMenu(item->scenePos().toPoint());
      }
   break;
  }
  }
  break;
  }
 }
 return QObject::eventFilter(o, e);
 }
void MainWindow::showContextMenu(const QPoint &pos)
{
Menu= new QMenu("Menu");
Submenu=Menu->addMenu(QIcon(":/img/pix.png"),"Pix");
Picture =Submenu->addAction(QIcon(":/img/pix.png"),"Pix");
connect(Picture, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(addPixBlock()));
Menu->exec(QCursor::pos());
}
void MainWindow::addPixBlock()
{
QPixmap pixmap(":/img/pix.png");
pix = scene->addPixmap(pixmap.scaled(70,50));
pix->setPos(x,y);
}
```

the block.h

```
#ifndef BLOCK_H
#define BLOCK_H
#include <QGraphicsPathItem>
class QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent;
class Block : public QGraphicsPathItem
{
public:
enum { Type = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 3 };
int type() const { return Type; }
Block(QGraphicsItem *parent = 0);
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget 
*widget);
bool eventFilter(QObject *, QEvent *);
};
#endif // BLOCK_H
```

the Block.cpp

```
#include "block.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QtWidgets>
class QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent;
Block::Block(QGraphicsItem *parent)
         : QGraphicsPathItem(parent)
{
QPainterPath p;
//<->,|,<->,|,roundness
p.addRoundedRect(0,0,80,50, 5, 5);
setPath(p);
setAcceptDrops(true);
setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
}
void Block::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, 
QWidget *widget)
{
Q_UNUSED(option)
Q_UNUSED(widget)
painter->setPen(QPen(QColor(67, 141, 220)));
painter->setBrush(QColor(67, 141, 220,100));
painter->drawPath(path());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you want to place a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` on top of another item, a better option is to set it as your `parentItem`.

On the other hand we can use an event filter but a better option in this case is to implement a custom `QGraphicsScene`, and when pressing with the left key it allows to drag the item, for that we use `QDrag` and we pass the data of the item, then we overwrite the event `dropEvent` where we will obtain the item and establish a new parent.

**graphicsscene.h**

```
#ifndef GRAPHICSSCENE_H
#define GRAPHICSSCENE_H

#include <QGraphicsScene>

class QMenu;
class QAction;

class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:
    using QGraphicsScene::QGraphicsScene;

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
    void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event) override;

private:
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *findPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *item);
    void createDrag(const QPointF &pos, QWidget *widget, QGraphicsItem *item);
    void showContextMenu(const QPointF &pos);
    void addPixBlock(QGraphicsItem *item);

    QMenu *menu;
    QMenu *submenu;
    QAction *picture;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *pix;
};

#endif // GRAPHICSSCENE_H
```

**graphicsscene.cpp**

```
#include "graphicsscene.h"

#include <QDrag>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QWidget>

void GraphicsScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    auto its =  items(QRectF(event->scenePos() - QPointF(1,1), QSize(3,3)));
    auto val = std::find_if(its.constBegin(), its.constEnd(), [](auto const& it){
        return it->type() > QGraphicsItem::UserType;
    });
    if(val == its.constEnd())
        return;
    if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton){
        showContextMenu(event->scenePos());
    }
    else{
        createDrag(event->scenePos(), event->widget(), *val);
    }

}

void GraphicsScene::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    QByteArray byteArray = event->mimeData()->data("Item");
    QGraphicsPixmapItem * item = *reinterpret_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem**>(byteArray.data());
    QGraphicsItem *item_parent = itemAt(event->scenePos(), QTransform());
    item->setParentItem(item_parent);
}

QGraphicsPixmapItem *GraphicsScene::findPixmapItem(QGraphicsItem *item){
    auto chs = item->childItems();
    auto  val = std::find_if(chs.constBegin(), chs.constEnd(), [](auto const& it){
            return static_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(it) != Q_NULLPTR;
});
    return val == chs.constEnd() ? Q_NULLPTR : static_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(*val);
}

void GraphicsScene::createDrag(const QPointF &pos, QWidget *widget, QGraphicsItem *item){
    QGraphicsPixmapItem *pix = findPixmapItem(item);
    if(pix == Q_NULLPTR)
        return;
    QByteArray byteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&pix),sizeof(QGraphicsPixmapItem*));
    QDrag *drag = new QDrag(widget);
    QMimeData * mimeData = new QMimeData;
    mimeData->setData("Item",byteArray);
    drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
    drag->setHotSpot(pos.toPoint()-pix->scenePos().toPoint());
    drag->setPixmap(pix->pixmap());
    drag->start();

}

void GraphicsScene::showContextMenu(const QPointF &pos)
{
    QGraphicsItem *item = itemAt(pos, QTransform());
    menu= new QMenu("Menu");
    submenu = menu->addMenu(QIcon(":/img/pix.png"),"Pix");
    picture = submenu->addAction(QIcon(":/img/pix.png"),"Pix");
    connect(picture, &QAction::triggered, [item, this](){
        addPixBlock(item);
    });
    menu->exec(QCursor::pos());
}

void GraphicsScene::addPixBlock(QGraphicsItem *item)
{
    if(findPixmapItem(item))
        return;
    QPixmap pixmap(":/img/pix.png");
    pix = addPixmap(pixmap.scaled(70,50));
    if(pix->parentItem() != item)
        pix->setParentItem(item);
}
```

Then we establish that new scene and add the `Block`s.

The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/49536899)