# Qt Drag and Drop for multiple QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: qt

I use the following code for drag and drop single images in a graphic scene inside event filter now I am trying to figure out how to apply this code for multiple image drag and drop selected at once

**Drag**

```
void MainWindow::createDrag(const QPointF &pos, QWidget *widget, 
                            QGraphicsItem *item){
   QGraphicsPixmapItem *pix =static_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem *>(item);
   QByteArray byteArray(reinterpret_cast<char*> 
   (&pix),sizeof(QGraphicsPixmapItem*));
   QDrag *drag = new QDrag(widget);
   QMimeData * mimeData = new QMimeData;
   mimeData->setData("Item",byteArray);
   drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
   drag->setPixmap(pix->pixmap());
   drag->start();
   }
```

**Drop**

```
void MainWindow::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event){

QByteArray byteArray = event->mimeData()->data("Item");
QGraphicsPixmapItem * pixmap = *reinterpret_cast<QGraphicsPixmapItem**> 
(byteArray.data());
QGraphicsItem *blockToBeDroped = itemAt(event->scenePos());
pixmap->setParentItem(blockToBeDroped);
}
```

Comment: you could explain me better, you do not want to drag and drop images but QGraphicsPixmapItem. On the other hand, assuming that you are working on the same project that helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49536899/draggable-pixmaps-inside-a-qgraphicsscene-of-graphic-items I suppose you want to select several blocks and drop it in another block, what would the images look like? Do you not think that one image would cover the other?

Comment: imagine its a grid of blocks (4x12) 4 rows and 12 columns and inside there are images I want to be able to do spesific drags and drops  for example move row 1 to row 2

Comment: That is an easy example, if you select items that do not belong to the same row or column, how should it work?

Comment: no I do not want to work that way, only move columns and rows

Comment: And as differences between the selection of rows or columns?

Comment: That is how the user would do to indicate that he wants to drag a row, and how he would indicate it is a column.

Comment: lets say that row 1 have 3 pictures on position 1,3,4 I want to be able move to the other 3 rows in the same position ,and the same for columns nothing else

Comment: your blocks have indexes?

Comment: yes they have indexes

Comment: Then provide a  [mcve], please